# please install a compatible android api level (15 or higher) -robotium

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, robotium-recorder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3LOL.png)

HI, I'm already search for the solution but don't get a clear solution that may help me to fixes this problem. I already use all the requirements as the API level higher than 15. but this problem appear again. can anyone help me. Thanks in advance. I'm a beginner in this field.

Comment: I am stuck in the same issue